# How to get a cell's column header and row's first td when I click a cell in grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to get a cell's column header and row's first td when I click a cell in grid?

I can get the td's text using :

```
trigger.find('td:first').attr('id')
```

Comment: How does your click handler look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such methods [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n8vt/).

For getting the position of a cell in the line, you can use `jQuery.fn.index` and for the first cell, you get the row with `$(this).closest("tr")` and then select the first cell with `.find("td:first")`.